# prevent OS X sleep whilst running specific launchd plist

Tags: macos, backup, launchd

I have a global launchd plist file that runs a backup script periodically. The script is a pretty simple bash script that sets up some variables and calls `duply`. However the plist doesn't seem to be preventing the system from going into sleep mode.

Is there a way of preventing the mac from going into sleep mode whilst this specific launchd plist and associated script are running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution that seems to be working is

`caffeinate -s [utility]`

This forces the system to stay awake until the `[utility]` closes.

> -s      Create an assertion to prevent the system from sleeping. This assertion is valid only when sys-tem system
>                tem is running on AC power.

The full man page explains more.

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/caffeinate.8.html

Answer (score 1):

I use the following to prevent my Mac sleeping:

```
pmset noidle
```

and then I use Ctrl-C to kill that and allow it to sleep again.

Comment: So am I right in saying that I can put `pmset noidle` at the beginning of my bash script and then `pmset idle` at the end and this should work?

Comment: Sorry, I"m not in a position to check at the moment but `pmset noidle` should work at the start at least to prevent sleeping - check the manpage and give it a try.

Comment: You may need to start it in the background and retain its process id and then kill it whenever you are happy to allow sleep.

Comment: @juliushibert There's also the newer `caffeinate` [command](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man8/caffeinate.8.html).

Comment: @null Top advice! Put it as an answer and have my vote.